# devtool configuration failed in webpack build

Tags: webpack, devtools

I migrated webpack version from 2 to 5.3.2. in devtool, I put 'cheap-source-map' as document from webpack. But webpack is returning below error in build.

> invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$". BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict. Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.

Can someone please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: did you get any answer for this problem?

Comment: Hi all. sorry for the delay to reply. It is due to source map plug in. Latest version of webpack don't need to use source map plug in